# chmod +w /var/log/messages seems to fail also for root user

Tags: permissions, root

Does anybody know why the root user can add read access for everybody to the /var/log/messages giving the commands:

```
$ ls -l /var/log/messages 
-rw------- 1 root root 161613 Aug  8 14:12 /var/log/messages
$ chmod +r /var/log/messages
$ ls -l /var/log/messages 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 161613 Aug  8 14:20 /var/log/messages
```

But with the same command can not add the write right:

```
$ chmod +w /var/log/messages
$ ls -l /var/log/messages 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 161613 Aug  8 14:20 /var/log/messages
```

Comment: "Does anybody know?", Yes! Everyone knows, who read the documentation/man page, as far as that the `umask` affects `chmod`.

Answer (score 3):

From the `chmod` man page:

> A combination of the letters ugoa controls which users' access to the file will be changed: the user who owns it (u), other users in the file's group (g), other users not in the file's group (o), or all users (a).  **If none of these are given, the effect is as  if  (a)  were given, but bits that are set in the umask are not affected.**

So, it's the `umask`; it appears to have the value 022.

Comment: I've found the way: please edit the /etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf and add in the option session the instruction perm(0666);

Comment: @PaxToYou It's enough if you just use the full notation: `chmod go+w messages`.

Comment: @PaxToYou Why do you want to make the logs writeable for everyone?